# How to operate on specific row values with ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to operate on specific row values with ORACLE SQL?

Here is my SQL syntax.

```
SELECT (BASICPAY + SUDANG)
     FROM(
     SELECT T2.*, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (
          SELECT T.*, (BASICPAY + SUDANG)
          FROM TBLINSA T
         WHERE SUBSTR(T.SSN, 8, 1) = 1
          ORDER BY BASICPAY + SUDANG DESC
      )T2
     )T3
WHERE RN = 3
UNION
SELECT (BASICPAY + SUDANG)
     FROM(
     SELECT T2.*, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (
          SELECT T.*, (BASICPAY + SUDANG)
          FROM TBLINSA T
         WHERE SUBSTR(T.SSN, 8, 1) = 2
          ORDER BY BASICPAY + SUDANG DESC
      )T2
     )T3
WHERE RN = 9
```

The result of is:

```
(BASICPAY+SUDANG)
2070000
2670000
```

Here we need to find the difference between 2070000 and 2670000 in row 1.

I'm curious how to get this difference.

Comment: Would be easier to help if you could setup db fiddle

Comment: There needs to be an aggregate somewhere. me thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subqueries in the *from* clause:

```
SELECT S1.TOTAL - S2.TOTAL
FROM (SELECT (BASICPAY + SUDANG) as TOTAL
      FROM (SELECT T2.*, ROWNUM AS RN 
            FROM (SELECT T.*
                  FROM TBLINSA T
                  WHERE SUBSTR(T.SSN, 8, 1) = 1
                  ORDER BY BASICPAY + SUDANG DESC
                 )T 2
           ) T3
       WHERE RN = 3
      ) S1 CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT (BASICPAY + SUDANG) AS TOTAL
       FROM (SELECT T2.*, ROWNUM AS RN
             FROM (SELECT T.*
                   FROM TBLINSA T
                   WHERE SUBSTR(T.SSN, 8, 1) = 2
                   ORDER BY BASICPAY + SUDANG DESC
                  ) T2
            ) T3
       WHERE RN = 9
      ) S2
```